# Translate view within the same View Group

Tags: android

[image: Translate view within the same Linear layout]

I want to translate this circle image percentage wise within the same view group. The New location could be anything 30% or 50% or 100% according to data I will get.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Post your tried code as well, whatever your have tried till now?

Comment: actually, I don't have any idea about the translation so do not have any code.

Comment: yes, but can you please elaborate the complete process or give a simple demo code to do percentage wise translation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
mContainerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        mContainerView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        // Start animation here so getHeight won't return 0

        int maxTranslateDistance = mContainerView.getHeight() - mCircleView.getHeight();

        float percent = 1;  // Within 0 - 1

        mCircleView.animate().translationY((int)(maxTranslateDistance * percent)).setDuration(0).start();
    }
});
```

`mContainerView` is your container `LinearLayout` and `mCircleView` is the circle view. You calculate the maximum distance can be translated by both the height, multiply by the percentage (0 - 1) to get the final distance.

You can remove `getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener` part if you start the animation after the layout is fully drawn on the screen.

Comment: Thanks, Tam I am trying this but did not get the result may I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I am searching my mistake. If I will not get then I will ask you for help.

Comment: You can debug if any of `getHeight` call return 0, or play around with `translateYBy`, `y` after `animate()` call if any of them fit your need

Comment: Glad I can help

Answer (score 2):

the LL should contain a space on top of the circle with height="0dp". when data received, you should set weight attribute of the space to 
100-(received_percentage). remember to set weight_sum of LL to 100.

Comment: Thanks, Omid nice idea I will implement this. but I can't vote because I have only 8 reputations well, votes will cast in future.